lagnchain selfqueryRetriever with regard to
This is how it is written in the schema when using the language chain self-query retriever.
I created the retriever after writing an example prompt using container and like. However, I get an error that I can't use container, like.
Your goal is to structure the user's query to match the request schema provided below.

<< Structured Request Schema >>
When responding use a markdown code snippet with a JSON object formatted in the following schema:

```json
{
    "query": string \ text string to compare to document contents
    "filter": string \ logical condition statement for filtering documents
}

The query string should contain only text that is expected to match the contents of documents. Any conditions in the filter should not be mentioned in the query as well.

A logical condition statement is composed of one or more comparison and logical operation statements.

A comparison statement takes the form: `comp(attr, val)`:
- `comp` (eq | ne | gt | gte | lt | lte | contain | like | in | nin): comparator
- `attr` (string):  name of attribute to apply the comparison to
- `val` (string): is the comparison value

A logical operation statement takes the form `op(statement1, statement2, ...)`:
- `op` (and | or | not): logical operator
- `statement1`, `statement2`, ... (comparison statements or logical operation statements): one or more statements to apply the operation to

Make sure that you only use the comparators and logical operators listed above and no others.
Make sure that filters only refer to attributes that exist in the data source.
Make sure that filters only use the attributed names with its function names if there are functions applied on them.
Make sure that filters only use format `YYYY-MM-DD` when handling date data typed values.
Make sure that filters take into account the descriptions of attributes and only make comparisons that are feasible given the type of data being stored.
Make sure that filters are only used as needed. If there are no filters that should be applied return "NO_FILTER" for the filter value.```




```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-5a63d86f57f7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 results = retriever.get_relevant_documents(
      2     "Please recommend me a computer estimate for LOL and Battleground"
      3 )
      4 
      5 for res in results:

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/structured_query.py in _validate_func(self, func)
     24         if isinstance(func, Comparator) and self.allowed_comparators is not None:
     25             if func not in self.allowed_comparators:
---> 26                 raise ValueError(
     27                     f"Received disallowed comparator {func}. Allowed "
     28                     f"comparators are {self.allowed_comparators}"

ValueError: Received disallowed comparator like. Allowed comparators are [<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, <Comparator.NE: 'ne'>, <Comparator.GT: 'gt'>, <Comparator.GTE: 'gte'>, <Comparator.LT: 'lt'>, <Comparator.LTE: 'lte'>]

I just did it because I said eq can work, but I can recognize it, but I think it's a problem with upgrading the Langchain library.

The above error indicates that the vector store you are using (whcih is not clear based on the details you have provided) does not support like operator. Check the last line in the error logs for the allowed operator for your vector store.
ValueError: Received disallowed comparator like. Allowed comparators are [<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, <Comparator.NE: 'ne'>, <Comparator.GT: 'gt'>, <Comparator.GTE: 'gte'>, <Comparator.LT: 'lt'>, <Comparator.LTE: 'lte'>]

